# Only seeing Wordpress changes when logged in as Admin - All cache cleared

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, clear-cache

I've made some changes to my wordpress site that are only showing up when I'm logged in as an admin. I've cleared all caches (that I know of) and tried on different browsers with totally cleared caches and it only works with admin.

Possible that I'm not clearing a certain cache that I don't know about? Any tips?

Comment: I went into my htaccess file and found remnants from last caching plugins. Deleted them and it works fine.

Leaving this question up in case it helps someone in the future.

Comment: which plugin you are using for cache?